# Why I'm getting 'cannot resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3' in my Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm using Intellij IDEA and I have a simple spring boot app.

I'm getting this error when I've imported the **pom.xml**

```
Cannot resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
```

Screenshot of the pom.xml :

[image]

Comment: Please add the pom.xml properly.

Comment: Please run `mvn clean install` first and check if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Add maven central repositories in your pom.xml. This looks missing in the image which you have shared.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Maven Central</name>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: The best is to add the central repo configuration to your maven settings.xml. It is a big mess if  your pom.xml contains this central repo condig.

Comment: It can be multiple ways. If it is a small project then I would say to maintain it in the one file but scope is getting bigger then ideally it should be there.